# CSS jQuery Dropline Menu - How to make the first line 33px?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to modify [Stu Nicholls' awesome menu](http://www.stunicholls.com/menu/jquery-dropline-7.html).

I want only the first line (HOME, SERVICES, PRODUCTS, PRIVACY) to be 33px and the following lines 22px... but can't get it to work.

Here's my html code:

```
<div id="menu">

    <ul id="dropline">

        <li class="top"><a href="#url">HOME</a></li>              

        <li class="top"><a class="down" href="#url">SERVICES</a>
            <ul class="sub">                    
                <li><a href="#url">Printing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#url">Photo Framing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#url">Retouching</a></li>
                <li><a href="#url">Archiving</a></li>                       
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="top current"><a class="down" href="#url">PRODUCTS</a>
            <ul class="sub"> 
                <li class="current"><a class="down" href="#url">Lenses</a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="#url">Telephoto</a></li>
                        <li class="current"><a class="down" href="#url">Zoom</a>
                            <ul class="sub">
                                <li><a href="#url">35mm to 125mm</a></li>
                                <li class="current"><a href="#url">50mm to 250mm</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#url">125mm to 500mm</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Mirror</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>            
                <li><a href="#url">Flash Guns</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="top"><a href="#url" id="privacy">PRIVACY</a></li>

    </ul> <!-- end ul dropline -->

</div> <!-- end menu -->
```

**Here's the CSS Code:**

```
#menu {
    position:relative;
    height:33px;
    background: url("../images/nav-bg.gif") repeat-x;
}
#dropline {
    position:relative;
    font-size:12px;
    height:33px;
}
#dropline, #dropline ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    width:1010px;
}
#dropline table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin:-1px -10px;
0 0;
    padding:0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    font-size:12px;
}
#dropline li {
    float:left;
    height:33px;
}
#dropline li a {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height:33px;
    line-height:33px;
    padding:0 20px 0 10px;
    font-family:tahoma, verdana, arial;
    font-size:13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color:#a49572;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#dropline li ul li a {
    color:#a49572;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-size:11px;
    text-transform:none;
}
#dropline li a.down {
    background:url(down.gif) no-repeat right center;
}
#dropline li ul li a.down {
    font-weight:bold;
}
#dropline li ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:33px;
    left:-9999px;
    z-index:10;
    background:url(fade.png);
}
#dropline li ul.floatRight li {
    float:right;
}
#dropline .sub {
    background: #c76023 url("../images/nav-sec-lines-bg.gif") repeat-x;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By 33px, I assume you mean height.

```
#dropline li {
    height: 22px;
}

#dropline li a {
    line-height: 22px;
}

#dropline > li {
    height: 33px;
}

#dropline > li a {
    line-height: 33px;
}
```

Integrate these rules into your CSS as appropriate, you may have to remove some rules you already have that will override these. This won't work in IE6, but even [Microsoft wants it dead](http://ie6countdown.com/), so don't worry bout it.

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately it doesn't work. If I modify `#dropline li ul` from `top:33px` to `top:22px` all the lines are 22px including the first one which I don't want that. Oh well... I'll leave all the lines 33px. Thanks again!

Comment: I never said to change the top attribute... If anything you can delete that rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't worried about older browser support, you can use the pseudo-element selector `:first-child`.

```
li:first-child {
    line-height: 33px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#dropline li.top {height: 33px;}` This will only target your top-level `li` tags because they all have the class `top`. Also, it will only target `li` items with the class `top` which means you could use it somewhere else if wanted(the class).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u just add some classes on them?

Dont use CSS child because it wont work on older browsers like IE7/IE8.